# Heroku ZipImportError: bad local file header

Tags: heroku, pip

I keep running into this strange Heroku build error. If I mess around with the ordering of my requirements.txt then the package that fails to build will change, but the build always ends with the exceptions:

```
ZipImportError: bad local file header in /app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-2.1-py2.7.egg
```

And

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 38: ordinal not in range(128)
```

You can see a full build log here: http://pastebin.com/BYw3Xp6u

Anyone know what's going on here?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem (bad local file header), it seems they have an issue with the new python buildpack.

So you can use the previous version of the buildpack by adding a config var :

```
heroku config:set BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python.git#5f96190eb5ccd05b90947f9a77d7ef0881816ef8
```

It should temporarily solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks @Norzn this solved the problem for me, but does this mean that my config will always use the custom buildpack or will it automatically get updated when Heroku fixes the problem?